# Is the "Duolingo gems" question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question got flagged as off-topic: [How do I send gems to another user in Duolingo?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/5938/how-do-i-send-gems-to-another-user-in-duolingo)  I completely agree with this flag, as it has nothing to do with learning languages.  However, I can't just ignore a score of +4, and 2000+ views.

The [on-topic page](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says the following questions are on-topic:

> Questions regarding the use of language-learning or teaching software or technology (i.e. Duolingo, Anki, etc.) in conjunction with the learning/teaching process.

On many sites, exceptions are made based on expertise, e.g. at Chinese.SE, we get questions about Chinese input methods and Chinese fonts (which are unrelated to the language).  The justification is that the Chinese.SE community is more familiar these topics than the sites where they are on-topic on paper.  It's conceivable we might make a similar exception here, and consider "Duolingo support" questions on-topic.

Hence I feel there's an argument both ways...

**Question**: Is the "Duolingo gems" question off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the more general question is **whether questions about how to use certain sites, apps and applications are on topic if the question is not about a function directly related to learning or teaching languages**. In my opinion, the answer is no.

To continue the analogy with Chinese SE: writing Chinese on a computer requires the use of an input method, but learning a language doesn't require virtual "gems". Other functions of Duolingo are directly relevant to language learning and may be on topic (but this probably requires a separate meta question).